# Ajax Post Parameter is Always Null in MVC app

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, parameters, null

I have a simple post that works in a test app

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Delete(string Id)
{
    ... delete record ...
}
```

JavaScript

```
function delAnnouncement(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("Delete", "Announcements")",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "Id": "03d23684-098a-4ae8-8fa2-7d9ce70d63ef" }), // Hard coded for testing
        success: function (data) {
            $("#AnnouncementsPH").replaceWith(data);
        }
    });        
}
```

I have created a simple test application and it works there.

I am looking for any ideas as to what may exist in the existing application that would always cause the id passed to be null.

**Things I have tried:**
Route Info is the same between the two applications.
They are both secure https websites.
Other forms on the existing website work as expected. This is the only place a javascript post with a parameter is used. It is just the new view that lists any system announcements.
As far as I can tell the HTML is valid.
Fiddler show the data is being sent.
I have tried to simply hard code in the `Id` to pass.

I have no idea what could be causing the **`Post`** not to work.

Thanks for any suggestions

Edit 1: here is the fiddler Raw post

```
POST https://localhost:44300/Announcements/Delete HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44300
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 39
Accept: */*
Origin: https://localhost:44300
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-TypeOfNotification: application/json; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Referer: https://localhost:44300/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: jetbrains.charisma.main.security.PRINCIPAL=NmI4YmFhZTExMThjZDZkZjNmZTBhMDNiZWM4NmY3MDYzZWNiMWE3M2ZmZDM5ODMwYjViMjczN2ZkZmU3YmZlZTpyb290; TCSESSIONID=233EBE63123BA35468235F441F54D7E4; ASP.NET_SessionId=ycnx1ejeyahzipwduux2quqz; __RequestVerificationToken=FnOKGFfBZKEBX4E0KBoV9133e5KK3h9Pd_OjDzNPjv7ifMTMk5uHUPmT621hOQFyOCwW5IhdewKLPDMs2_9jY2vVwrHLYOU9f0F86mN-NoQ1; .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=V8ZnbAx_2_H1Wx946VLcQ235XplzC-uvKdw4CP7Sm8ZVnJu9pG63EuzC0ptOZZNBvzZkRjB0RJS25Pn1WHOzeQSrqoWl87keqRDS6_vMwZ9L6PgKU0rJz7OhD7eKps8l3tzR097zI5WbU_chUZFKLLw1c__rfN3Fy6BbHC1qNtgx0C86AShhG5EsNiruYqJZn-Uj7Z2h75YcZctCFniMyuzD-9RetcMjkN3_PbAJg-_urfntG9NwsMEQdBf1b3K9H3GP_wUYRhnbQdNZpuAkAEa6bVfJiHrnKFhnhLkP8BAfocbMKES1wQKbXBfcNn62cEKUu3On3lHNCNN4zEvOhxF1aDaBk-yghOtvtNkROeFTKMQFD0U-XXAf-RKm0Nwgp1Tb2Ip2U42vshDRNGXQSkOojisVUxiPmkrxDtckNycQd0br1cFSqxfeXyg3cg_vKUP1VMBQcBQxZO6MVLSCDdcpANyoE43IoLp3BHgURJZP88vF18JfVV646XGOZ3QU

Id=03d23684-098a-4ae8-8fa2-7d9ce70d63ef
```

As you can see the Id is posted to the controller, just not parsed and supplied to the parameter in the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can append the parameter like:

```
var targeturl = '@Url.Action("Test", "Controller")?id=' + ID;

$.ajax({
    url: targeturl,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) { },
    error: function (data) { }
});
```

Or you may use the jQuery ajax data parameter directly:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action("Test", "Controller")',
  data: { id: "your-id" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

References: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks. The Get works, any idea as to why the post does not?  I have marked this as fixed.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't found this answer anywhere else so I had to discover it through experimentation.

1. You'll find that in your controller, it's receiving a `Request.Form` object and if you look in `Request.Form[0]` you'll find your data. The reason that there's data in the form but MVC is seeing it as `null` is that the key to the form element being POSTed is `""` (blank).
2. So client side, you have to set content type properly, and precede your data with `"data=" + JSON.stringify(mydata)`, where `"data"` is the key name you are adding.

Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    data: "data="+JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
```

On the server side, your `[HttpPost]` endpoint has to have as its input a variable with the *same name* as the key you declared in your AJAX, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index (string data) // <-- key name
{
   MyObjectType MyFinalObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObjectType (data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to use `JSON.stringify` for the data. By default they will get values will be sent as Jason using ajax.

Try This

```
data : { Id: "03d23684-098a-4ae8-8fa2-7d9ce70d63ef" }
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly no joy, I get the same result.  I do know if I create a quick application and add the code I posted, that it does work, just not in the existing application. Yet I cant see any real difference between the two applications that would cause it to work in the one but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me, so instead I successfully solved with:

Javascript with JQuery:

```
function sendAjaxPostRequest(url, id, value) {
    $.post(url+'?id='+id+'&value='+value,
        function (returnedData) {
            console.log(returnedData);
        });
}
```

C# ASP.NET:

```
// POST api/<controller>
public void Post(int id, string value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{id}: {value}");
}
```

The `Post` parameter list signature must match the POST request url, e.g. `?id=123` means there must be a method `Post(int id)`. Hope this helps someone.

Make sure to **test your back-end with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps)** before you blaim your front-end JS !

---

Strangely JS's `$.ajax({ ... });` did not work by itself, but if I used *both* JQuery's `$.post(...);` and `$.ajax({...})` POST requests, then both of them worked - very odd.

Answer (score 0):

I have wasted nearly a day on this, but finally got this working using JQuery and making sure I waited for response before continuing.  Working client script:

```
 $.post('/ex/edited/', {
            ExId: @Model.ExId.ToString(),
            ExName: ExName
        })

            .done(function (response) {
                if (response.redirectUrl) {
                    window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
                } else {
                    alert(response.errorMsg);
                }
            });
```