# asp.net mvc ajax post returns 404 not found

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to do an ajax request using jquery ajax function. I have a very strange behaviour. My folder structure ist like this:

[image: folder structure]

My client-side ajax call (in UserManagement/Index.cshtml) looks like the following:

```
var rolename = viewModel.roleName();
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '@Url.Action("AddRole", "UserManagement")',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: { rolename: rolename },
     success: function(data) {
         var role = new Role(rolename);
         model.addRole(role);
         model.appendItem("#accordion", role.getItem());
         viewModel.roleName("");            
     }
});
```

In my UserManagementController.cs I have the following actions:

```
    // GET: /UserManagement/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var users = context.Users.ToList();
        var roles = context.Roles.ToList();


        ViewBag.Users = users;
        ViewBag.Roles = roles;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /UserManagement/AddRole
    [HttpPost]
    public string AddRole(string rolename)
    {

        Response.StatusCode = 200;
        return "gsfgdg";
    }
```

I already tried to use a GET instead of POST or to change AddRole to void type and anything other but I can't get this to work. I always receive a "404 not found".
Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your browser console what is url called?

Comment: Try with contentType removed from ajax call

Comment: try **append the parameter** check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25050306/2218697)

Answer (score 4):

Your case will work if you remove Content-Type.

**`Case 1: If we use Content-Type: "application/json"`**

When you request with a Content-Type of application/json, in server side ScriptServices expects data as JSON serialized string.

However, we can see `"Invalid JSON primitive ***"` is usually the result in response.

Here we should understand to pass the jQuery's "data" option as "{'param':'value'}", not {'param':'value'}.

So in your case, to achieve the solution: we need to supply `data` as below

```
var rolename = viewModel.roleName();
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '@Url.Action("AddRole", "UserManagement")',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: "{ 'rolename':'" + rolename +"' }",
     success: function(data) {
         var role = new Role(rolename);
         model.addRole(role);
         model.appendItem("#accordion", role.getItem());
         viewModel.roleName("");            
     }
});
```

**`Case 2: If we skip Content-Type: "application/json"`**

We should supply jQuery's "data" option as JSON object {'param':'value'} or {param:'value'}. (as you did)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I now removed the content-type section and also tried the other approach.. Still receiving 
POST http://localhost:47174/UserManagement/AddRole 404 (Not Found) 
should be the right URL but it cannot be found. I have no idea why this problem occurs. Seems to be a routing problem...

Comment: Yes you're right. Please check the Routing :) or show us what route-mapping you have in RouteConfig!

Comment: In fact I didn't know I have to configure the routing on my own...
I just added two routes but still doesn't work:

`routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Test",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "UserManagement", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AddRole",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{rolename}",
                defaults: new { controller = "UserManagement", action = "AddRole", rolename = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`

Comment: Above mappings were fine. Check controller class declaration `public class UserManagementController : Controller`

Comment: The declaration is as you wrote. For now I created a new ASP.NET MVC Project using an older version. This works fine for me. It's not a real solution but I am not able to waste time anymore trying to fix the project...

Comment: There is some other top level issue you have in your project. Please check Global.ascx.cs and config settings. It should work with MVC 5 with default settings, I tried(mvc5 in VS2013) to replicate the issue in my box but couldn't :(