# asp.net mvc5 ajax post returns 404 after switching to IIS 7.5 from IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making an MVC5 app on Visual Studio 2012.

I wrote up an AJAX call and got it to work just fine, then I switched its web server to IIS 7.5 from the previously set IIS Express, now I get 404's on the AJAX calls when I run it.

(everything works fine if I switch back to IIS Express)

is there something I am missing?

FYI, I looked at this link first, but it didn't solve my problem:  [asp.net mvc ajax post returns 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371688/asp-net-mvc-ajax-post-returns-404-not-found)

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetExpenseData()
{
    var expenses = new ExpenseGridModel();
    expenses.Populate(); //todo: filter

    return Json(expenses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

AJAX call (in expenseGrid.cshtml):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $().ready(function () {

        var $editExpenseDiv = $('#editExpenseDiv');

        $editExpenseDiv.hide();

        $.ajax({
                url: '/Main/GetExpenseData',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST'
            })
            .success(function (result) {
                LoadGrid(result, $("#expenseTable"), $editExpenseDiv, "This is the EDIT EXPENSE Div.");
            })
            .error(function(xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            });
    });

</script>
```

Index.html:

```
--- BreadCrumb Bar ---

<br/><br/>
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_ExpenseGrid", Model.ExpenseGridModel);
}

<br/>

@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_NotificationGrid", Model.NotificationGridModel);
}
```

Route Config:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Main", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: check url "not found". is your site in root directory? localhost/main or localhost/miSite/main?

Comment: the virtual directory is pointed to the web project folder, and that loads the page ok, just not the AJAX calls.  the error points to : http://localhost/Main/GetExpenseData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok this did it:

In the AJAX call, I put:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetExpenseData","Main")',
```

in place of:

```
url: '/Main/GetExpenseData',
```

Comment: ..according to fiddler, that target url is the same:  `POST /Main/GetExpenseData HTTP/1.1` .  I can't say that I fully understand why it works, however.. as its the same..