# When sending jQuery post to MVC controller getting 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm sending from view using jQuery to MVC post action

```
function DoSomething(passedId) {
   $.ajax({
             method: "POST",
             dataType: 'text',                       
             url: '/MyController/SomeAction/',
             data: { id: passedId}
          }).done(function (data) {
              //                        
  });
}
```

And inside MyController

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SomeAction(int id)
 {
     ...
 }
```

In Firebug console I'm getting 404 error.

Comment: Your dataType says 'text', is that what you are expecting back in your controller action?

Comment: Have you checked the rewrite config for the path you are using, is that all good?  Can you post the rewrite rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't said which version of jquery you are using. Please check jquery version and in case that this version is < 1.9.0 you should instead of

```
method: "POST"
```

use

```
type: "POST"
```

this is an alias for method, and according to [jquery official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

```
function DoSomething(passedId) {    
    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             dataType: 'text',                       
             url: '/MyController/SomeAction/',
             data: { id: passedId}
           }).done(function (data) {                                        
               ...
          });
}
```

Tested above code and it works (*each request enter inside mvc controller http post SomeAction action*).

Comment: also we can **append the parameter** check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25050306/2218697)

Answer (score 3):

In the RFC 2616 the code `404`  indicates that the server has not found anything matching the Request-URI.

So you need to look at your URL parameter.
Try the MVC conventional call using :

```
url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "MyController")',
```

Comment: I am glad I could help , one day you will help me or help someone else.
Happy coding

Comment: @JasonWilczak no it doesn't , but he's using the script inside the MVC view.

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker I stand corrected, I missed that part.

Comment: No problem @JasonWilczak 
Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm aware of what 404 error represents. Trried this already, doesnt help. Same error. Double checked url and route config everything looks ok.

Comment: can you try to manually go that resource to test if your routing is working or not . Run your application and go to " yourhostinfo/MyController/SomeAction

Answer (score 1):

**To resolve the 404 issue:**

1. There are a few options to resolve this.  You controller/action cannot be find the way it is describe.

   -If you are in a view that is in the controller for which the action  your are trying to call is located, then:

   **url: 'SomeAction',**

   -If you are trying to call an action from another controller, OtherController, for example, then:

   **url: 'Other/SomeAction',**

   -To add to another answer, if you are calling your ajax inside the view (and NOT in a javascript file) then you can also use (for a controller called SomeController):

   **url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "Some")',**

**Additional Items Of Note:**

1. You do not specify a content type for json (contentType indicates what you are sending):

   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
2. I can't tell, based on your action if you are expecting 'text' or something else.  However, unless expecting 'json', I would remove the data part.
3. You need to stringify your data

   JSON.stringify(data: { id: passedId}),

In the end, I would expect it to look something like:
function DoSomething(passedId) {

```
var url = "SomeAction"; //if action is in OtherController then: "Other/SomeAction"
$.ajax({
             method: "POST",                       
             url: url,
             data: JSON.stringify({ id: passedId}),
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
          }).done(function (data) {
              //                        
  });
}
```

Comment: contentType is what jQuery sends to your script.  I don't think his application is expecting json.

Comment: contentType is what is being sent to the server.  The controller action is expecting an object and will parse the json string appropriately to the action parameter model.

Comment: I don't think it would return 404 if datatype was the issue. maybe it would.  but the question is about a 404 issue, is it not?  So why all this about datatype etc..   The datatype is valid,  and the default content type is fine.

Comment: Yes, a resolution to the 404 is part of the answer, however, I see nothing wrong with expressing a way to assist OP in improving their current code.

Answer (score 0):

The slash at the beginning of this designates an absolute path, not a relative one.

```
/MyController/SomeAction/
```

You should include a URL or relative path.. maybe

```
'MyController/SomeAction/ajax.php'
```

or the full URL

```
'http://example.com/myajaxcontroller/someaction/ajax.php'
```

or stolen from the other guys answer

```
url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "MyController")',
```

> **To address others on here, I don't think the datatype is the
>   problem...**  OP says "I'm getting 404 error."

- `contentType` is the type of data you're sending, so
  application/json; charset=utf-8 is a common one, as is
  application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, which is the
  **default**.
- `dataType` is what you're expecting back from the server: json, html,
  **text**, etc. jQuery will use this to figure out how to populate the success function's parameter.

Answer (score -1):

use the following `ajax call`

```
var datum = { id: passedId };
$.ajax({
    url: url,                        // your url
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(datum),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    beforeSend: function () {

    },
    complete: function () {

    },
    success: function (user, status, XHR) {

    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {

    }
});
```

**UpDated**
`public ActionResult SomeAction(int id){}` should accept `string` parameter instead of `int`

Comment: You should indicate why they should use that call AND the part that seems to most important (url) to OP's question isn't explained here.

Answer (score -1):

Write the code this way:

```
function DoSomething(passedId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'yourController/SomeAction',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { id: passedId},
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (ex) {alert(ex.responseText)},
                success: function (data)
                {
                    if (data.Results != null) {
                        //use the return values                                
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

and the controller

```
public JsonResult SomeAction(int id)
    {
        try
        {   
            return Json(new { Results = "Text To return or send some object or an list, etc"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Finally, check that the controller has its respective view. :)
and and the library of "jQuery" updated.
just in case.

Comment: men I tell you. look my solution "type: 'post'"

Comment: and finally I will comment that check if your library up to date.