# 404 Not Found Ajax jquery MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I  created an MVC3 project in Visual Studio 2013. The view engine is razor.First I write jquery.ajax in @section Scripts {} in view(cshtml) it works fine. But I seperate script in .js file and debugging I get error : 
(debugging IIS Express)

IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found
...
More Information:   This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request again.
..

My jquery function(archive.js) :

```
jQuery.AjaxGetProjects = function (dropdownId, detailDropDownId, authorized) {

var projectId = $(dropdownId).val();
if (projectId != null && projectId != '') {
    var url =
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetProjects", "Archive")',
        data: {
            'projectId': projectId,
            'authorized': authorized
        },
        success: function (departman) {
            var length = 0;
            $(detailDropDownId).empty();
            $.each(departman, function (index, proje) {
                length = length + 1;
                $(detailDropDownId).append($('<option/>', {
                    value: proje.Value,
                    text: proje.Text,
                    selected: proje.Selected
                }));
            });
            if (length == 2) {
                $(detailDropDownId).trigger('change');
            }

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            // bu kısımda eğer ajax işlemi başarısız ise
            // hata mesajı verebiliriz.
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Controller :

```
public class ArchiveController : BaseController
{
   ...
   public ActionResult GetProjects(int projectId, bool authorized)
    {

        IArchive arch = WcfServiceHandler.GetDmsService<IArchive>();

        List<Poco> list = arch.GetProjects(UserManager.GetUserInfo(), projectId);
        var t = MvcHelper.GetDropDownList<Poco>(list, "NAME", "ID", "");
        return Json(t, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I tried this but not work (I got a new error: resource cannot be found ):

```
  <system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

please help..

Comment: `'@Url.Action("GetProjects", "Archive")',` is razor code. Razor code is not parsed in external script files. You need to define a variable in the main view and then access it from the script file

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you give example please.I am completely new in MVC.

Comment: In the main view `var myUrl = '@Url.Action("GetProjects", "Archive")';` and in the script file `$.ajax({ url: myUrl , ....`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use Razor inside a JavaScript file (unless you use something like the [RazorJS](http://john.katsiotis.com/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files) extension). If you look at your JS in the browser dev tools you'll see that the url outputted is:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetProjects", "Archive")',
```

When it should be:

```
url: www.yoursite.com/Archive/GetProjects
```

To fix it, you could make a method call from your view to that JS and pass in the URL, something like:

View:

```
<script>
    callMethod('@Url.Action("GetProjects", "Archive")');
</script>
```

Then your JS would be:

```
function callMethod(url) {
   ....
```

Or failing that, you code hard code it to be:

```
url: '/Archive/GetProjects'
```

But be careful if you're deploying to a site within a sub-directory, that link won't be valid.

Comment: also we can **append the parameter** check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25050306/2218697)

Comment: Turning @url.action 's to direct url worked for me. Only the pathing must be checked. Evaluations that .net framework doing is not done while the program running on the server after published.

Answer (score 1):

javascript cannot use razor syntax so the @Url.Action("GetProjects", "Archive") will not work, try passing in the post URL as a parameter or hardcode it e.g.

```
jQuery.AjaxGetProjects = function (dropdownId, detailDropDownId, authorized) {

var projectId = $(dropdownId).val();
if (projectId != null && projectId != '') {
var url =
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Archive/GetProjects',
    data: {
        'projectId': projectId,
        'authorized': authorized
    },
    success: function (departman) {
        var length = 0;
        $(detailDropDownId).empty();
        $.each(departman, function (index, proje) {
            length = length + 1;
            $(detailDropDownId).append($('<option/>', {
                value: proje.Value,
                text: proje.Text,
                selected: proje.Selected
            }));
        });
        if (length == 2) {
            $(detailDropDownId).trigger('change');
        }

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        // bu kısımda eğer ajax işlemi başarısız ise
        // hata mesajı verebiliriz.
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

OR

```
jQuery.AjaxGetProjects = function (dropdownId, detailDropDownId, authorized, postUrl) {

var projectId = $(dropdownId).val();
if (projectId != null && projectId != '') {
var url =
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: postUrl,
    data: {
        'projectId': projectId,
        'authorized': authorized
    },
    success: function (departman) {
        var length = 0;
        $(detailDropDownId).empty();
        $.each(departman, function (index, proje) {
            length = length + 1;
            $(detailDropDownId).append($('<option/>', {
                value: proje.Value,
                text: proje.Text,
                selected: proje.Selected
            }));
        });
        if (length == 2) {
            $(detailDropDownId).trigger('change');
        }

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        // bu kısımda eğer ajax işlemi başarısız ise
        // hata mesajı verebiliriz.
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
}
```